# How to make cell array same length after padding zeros

Tags: matlab, cell, padding

[This is data matrix having 2*159 cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inBZS.png) 
In the data matrix so many columns ( 2 vectors) having different length . I want to pad zeros which have the minimum length. Number of zeros should be

```
[max(length(Vector 1))-min(length(Vector 2))]
```

Now I want add zeros in the cell which have minimum length. and want to make length equal in each column if column have same length than no problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = max(max(cellfun(@(x)size(x,2),data)))
cellfun(@(x)[x, zeros(1,n-numel(x))], data, 'uni', 0)
```

---

The above was finding one single max value to pad the cells to. I realise now that you actually want this max calculated on a per column basis:

```
n = max(cellfun(@(x)size(x,2),data))
cellfun(@(x,n)[x, zeros(1,n-numel(x))], data, repmat(num2cell(n),2,1), 'uni', 0)
```

At this point it might be more intuitive to just use a loop

```
for col = 1:size(data,2)
    n = max(size(data{1,col},2),size(data{2,col},2));
    for row = 1:2
         x = data{row,col};
         data{row,col} = [x, zeros(1,n-numel(x))];
    end
end
```

Comment: `cellfun(@(x)[x, zeros(1,n-numel(x))],data,'UniformOutput',false)`

Comment: `x` is each of the cells in the input variable `data`. Consider `cellfun` to be a loop. The first iteration is `data{1} = [data{1}, zeros(1,n-numel(data{1}))]`. Note that you need to include the `,'UniformOutput',false` as I wrote in my comment. It won't work without it.

Comment: Is there any for loop required to do this

Comment: it is not working .. can u explain more in terms of my data  matrix and code.

Comment: @RahulKumarVijay `x` is just a dummy variable used to create an anonymous function. You don't need a loop as `cellfun` does the looping internally. What `cellfun` does is it applies the function specified in it's first argument to every cell of the cell array. So if that function is `@(x)size(x,2)` then for every element of the cell array, it returns the number of columns. Note that StewieGriffin is absolutely right, you need to specify that the output is not uniform. Apologies for the typo. See my edited answer.

Comment: @StewieGriffin thanks a lot ,   but still  it is not working for my data.

Comment: @RahulKumarVijay what does "not working" mean specifically

Comment: My data Matrix having 2 rows in 159 columns as you can see. Lets suppose data{1,2} have length 4402 and data{2,2} have 4400. These length are different now I have to add zeros in data{2,2} at the end to make length equal to data{1,2}. I have to do this in each column.

Comment: @RahulKumarVijay ok I see, you want the max to be per column. I understood it to be over the entire array. I'll adjust my answer accordingly