# Expand cell elements column wise in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell with unequal sized double elements.

For example

```
cc2 = 
[1x32 double]    
[1x3 double]    
[1x3 double]
[1x2 double]    
[1x457 double]    
[1x200 double]
[1x23 double]              
[1x10 double]
.
.    
[so on]
```

Every cell element is `1xn` where `n>=2`

I want to expand each cell element column-wise into its constituent doubles.

I tried something like this but this does not work

```
lens = sum(cellfun('length',cc2(:,1)),2);
out = zeros(numel(lens),max(lens));
out(bsxfun(@le,[1:max(lens)],lens)) = horzcat(cc2{:});
```

The individual elements are expanding row-wise but I need them to expand column-wise.

For example

```
input = {[1,2,3];[4];[5,6]};
output = [1,2,3;4,0,0;5,6,0];
```

Could someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you expect your output to look like? Do you want it padded with zeros?

Comment: Yes padded with zeroes is fine but i want them to expand coulmnwise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does

> expand each cell element column-wise into its constituent doubles

mean? Can you please provide an example input and output. So for example if your input is

```
C = {[1,2,3];
     [4];
     [5,6]}
```

Then what do you want as an output?

If you want this

```
E = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

then try

```
E = [C{:}]
```

If you want

```
E = [1,2,3;
     4,0,0;
     5,6,0]
```

Then try something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207153/1011724):

```
n = max(cellfun(@(x)size(x,2),C))
Ecell = cellfun(@(x)[x, zeros(1,n-numel(x))], C, 'uni', 0);
E = cat(1,E{:})
```

Note that `Ecell` in the code above will be equal to

```
Ecell == {[1,2,3];
          [4,0,0];
          [5,6,0]}
```

which is yet another valid interpretation of your question.

Comment: I want E = [1,2,3;4,0,0;5,6,0];

Comment: @EyesOfÖzil please add that to your question. Also, my answer is updated with code for that.

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for. Thank you!